# Erro para retornar valor dart/ flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Boa noite pessoal.
Estou tentando aprender usar o bloc com rxdart. Estou tendo dificuldade em recuperar o valor da API 
Quando debugo não sei se aparece um exception segue imagem, mais tem resultado mais ao colocar apresenta erro segue 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

segue codigo completo 
API_SERVICE
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Books_bloc
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

bookModel
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

booktile
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desde Já agradeço.

Comment: Você precisa fornecer mais informações, principalmente no erro que é apresentado, ou no comportamento que você espera que estivesse acontecendo. Uma dica é colocar o código em texto, para que alguém possa utilizá-lo para testar e simular o problema, fica difícil debugar algo através de imagens. Segue um link para como postar código https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido com remoção do bloc deixando somente com setState.

Comment: Marque sua pergunta como concluída então, para melhor organização.